# if else block code execution issue

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run the below code but it always prints the first line 2 times, it never goes in `elif` statement.

```
import re

fileOpen = open('C:\\Python36\\execrice\\test2.txt')
str1 = '  switchport trunk allowed vlan'
str2 = '  switchport trunk allowed vlan add'
for line in fileOpen:
    if line.startswith(str1):
        print ("first line")
    elif line.startswith(str2):
        print ("second line")
```

contents of file

```
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 2,4-24,27,30-36,38-39,41-46,48-50
  switchport trunk allowed vlan add 74,678-680,1101-1114,1201-1251
```

Comment: So, what is `fileOpen`?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do instead?

Comment: the complete code is import re

fileOpen = open('C:\\Python36\\execrice\\test2.txt')
str1 = '  switchport trunk allowed vlan'
str2 = '  switchport trunk allowed vlan add'
for line in fileOpen:
    if line.startswith(str1):
        print ("first line")
    elif line.startswith(str2):
        print ("second line")
fileOpen.close()

Answer (score 0):

`str1` is a prefix of `str2`. Thus, if the `elif`condition is true, the `if`condition will be true as well. Flip the order of your conditions, and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming fileOpen are the file's lines.

Switch your conditions. You're checking if the lines are starting with str1 and then str2. However, str2 is including str1. All the lines that are starting by str2 are also starting by str1.